# iPhone 6 Plus website display issue

Tags: html, css, iphone, ios8

I just got a new iPhone 6+ and tried to check my website on it (in both Safari & Chrome) and realised that it is displaying funny.

[There is a white strip that runs down the right side of the website that shouldn't be there (click here)](http://imgur.com/QiJV5PJ)

[It should look like this (this is a Xcode iOS sim which displays fine)](http://imgur.com/n9PyM0y)

Can anyone confirm it with their iPhone 6/6+ ?

Any ideas on what it is and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: If I knew what was causing it I would be able to fix it myself. The issue only occurs on my iPhone 6 plus as far as I can tell and I've checked it on other various devices: iPad, Xcode iOS simulator, the Squarespace7 device view mode....

Comment: You haven't provided a link or any meaningful code...we can't diagnose an image.- http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Sorry new here...

I wasn't sure what was causing the problem because my website displayed correctly on most platforms but my iPhone 6 plus (and my mums old HTC), and wasn't sure which part of my CSS code to show you all..

Anyways I managed to fix it.. I changed the CSS method I was using to create the full browser width header bar from a border script to a negative margin one... seemed to fix the problem..

If anyone else experiences this and wants help you can hit me up...